# Remove extra spaces html in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have code:

```
@foreach($tag->categories as $category)
    {{$loop->first ? '' : ','}} <a href="{{ route('showcategory', $category) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

In output I get result:

`Category1 , Category2`.

How I can remove space on the left? I need get:

`Category1, Category2`.

Comment: by using `trim()` or `ltrim()` i think???

Comment: @devpro not working: https://imgur.com/7R5KdKG

Comment: plz chk answer  ...

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php) method or the [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) method:

```
trim($category->name);
```

or

```
str_replace(' ', '', $category->name);
```

str_replace will replace all spaces in the string, not just the spaces in the beginning and the end of the string

trim removes the spaces just from the beginning and the end

You coud also use the [`ltrim`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ltrim.php) method suggested by @devpro:

```
ltrim($category->name);
```

This will remove the spaces from the beginning of the string

Comment: or ltrim for left hand side

Comment: i didnt know about this one, i will edit my answer, thanks for the tip @devpro!

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('showcategory', $category) }}">{{ ltrim($category->name) }}` not working. I get : `Category 1 , Category 2`

Answer (score 1):

It's not about trimming at all. It's about a space you put between your loop condition and tag start. So following line should fix your problem:

```
{{$loop->first ? '' : ','}}<a href="{{route('showcategory', $category)}}">{{trim($category->name)}}</a>
```